# Testing two forms on one page the `press` directive always submits the second form

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit, laravel-5.1

I am using Laravel 5.1 and whenever I test a page with two forms the second form is always submitted. If I remove the second form, or swap the order of the forms, the test works (but other tests then break). The page behaves as expected in the browser. Any help is appreciated.

**edit.blade.php**

```
    @section('content')
    <!-- Update Form -->
            {!! Form::model($article,
                    [
                        'id'=>'editForm', 
                        'method' => 'PATCH', 
                        'action' => ['ArticlesController@update', $article->id] 
                    ]) !!}

    <!-- Title Field -->
        {!! Form::label('title', 'Title:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('title', null, ['id' => 'title']) !!}

    <!-- Content Field -->
        {!! Form::label('content', 'Content:') !!}
        {!! Form::textarea('content', null, ['id' => 'content']) !!}

    <!-- Save Button -->
        {!! Form::submit('Save', ['id' => 'save']) !!}

        {!! Form::close() !!}

    <!-- Delete Form -->
        {!! Form::model($article,
                [
                    'id'=>'deleteForm', 
                    'method' => 'DELETE', 
                    'action' => ['ArticlesController@destroy', $article->id] 
                ]) !!}

    <!-- Delete Button -->
        {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['id' => 'delete']) !!}

        {!! Form::close() !!}
    @stop
```

**ArticlesTest.php**

```
 /**
  * @group articles
  * @test
  */
public function it_edits_an_article()
{
    //$this->markTestSkipped('Test doesn\'t work with two forms on one page.');

    $article1 = factory(App\Articles\Article::class)->make();
    $article2 = factory(App\Articles\Article::class)->make();

    $user = factory(User::class)->create();

    $user->articles()->save($article1);
    $this->seeInDatabase('articles', 
        [
            'title' => $article1->title,
            'user_id' => $user->id
        ]);

    $this->actingAs($user)
        ->visit($this->articlesUrl)
        ->see($article1->title)
        ->visit('/articles/'.$article1->slug.'/edit')
        ->type($article2->title, '#title')
        ->type($article2->content, '#content')
        ->press('Save') //this presses the delete button
        ->seePageIs($this->articlesUrl)
        ->see($article2->title)
        ->visit('/whats-new/'.$article1->slug)
        ->see($article2->content)
        ->visit('/latest/'.$article2->slug)
        ->see($article2->content)
        ->seeInDatabase('articles', ['title' => $article2->title]);
}
```

Comment: do 2 forms have save in the submit button? can you place the html generated from the code?

Comment: @TzookBarNoy Duh! Add an answer and I'll give you the bounty.

Comment: you probably wasted a lot of time because of this small thing :/

Comment: approve my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Your two forms probably have a button with the text "Save"

so when you use

```
->press('Save')
```

they are both clicked.